# getErrorStream not returning error in Java

Tags: java

I am creating a program that is going to run certain programs through the command line through a pl/sql function calling a java program.  The problem I am currently having is when I test the program with a file I know is not there the input stream returns a null value and it does not get the error stream.  I do not think I can use ProcessBuilder to merge error and input because if there is an error I would to return a value to the function in pl/sql to stop and copy an error code into a database.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
public class runScriptNew {

    private static boolean error = false;

    public static String run(String command)
    {
        ExecutorService threadExecutor;
        String retVal = null;
        try
        {
            String cmd = command;
            System.out.println("Starting the command..");
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C " + cmd);

            threadExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
            threadExecutor.execute(new StreamGobbler(p.getInputStream()));
            threadExecutor.execute(new StreamGobbler(p.getErrorStream(), true));

            p.waitFor();  // Wait for proc to complete.
            threadExecutor.shutdown();

            if(error == true)
            {
                retVal = "ERROR";
            }
            else
            {
                retVal = "OK";
            }
            System.out.println(error);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            retVal = e.toString();
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    public static class StreamGobbler implements Runnable
    {
        private InputStream input;
        private Boolean errorToken = false;

        public StreamGobbler(InputStream inStream)
        {
            input = inStream;
        }
        public StreamGobbler(InputStream inStream, Boolean bool)
        {
            input = inStream;
            errorToken = bool;
        }

        public void run() {
            StringBuffer line = new StringBuffer();
            BufferedReader buffRead = null;
            try
            {
                buffRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

                    while (buffRead.readLine() != null)
                    {
                        line.append(buffRead.readLine());
                        line.append("\n");
                        if (errorToken == true)
                        {
                            error = true;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(line.toString());
                    buffRead.close();
            }
            catch( IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                error = true;
            }
            finally
            {
                try {
                    buffRead.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    import java.io.*;

  public class runScript {
  public static String run(String args) throws IOException{
  String retVal = null;
  int errorNum;
    try
    {
        String cmd = args;
        System.out.println("Starting the command..");
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C " + cmd); 
        errorNum = p.waitFor();  // Wait for proc to complete.

        //if errorNum does not equal 0 then there was an error while handling the 
        //command
        if(errorNum != 0)
        {
            retVal = "ERROR";
        }
        else
        {
            retVal = "OK";
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        retVal = e.toString();
    }

    return retVal;

  }
}
```

Checking the waitFor() call fixed the issue.  Turns out I did not need to handle the input and error streams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there's a lot going on here, but I'll do the best I can to help you out.

First, the system command `cmd /c <command>` executes `<command>` then terminates.  This means a separate process is started without its streams redirected anywhere.  Is there a reason you can't execute `<command>` directly?

Second, I don't think (I don't know for sure, but I don't think) that `Runtime.exec(String)` executes the full string like you think it does.  I believe `Runtime.exec(String)` is used to execute a system command with no arguments.  You should use `Runtime.exec(String[])` to pass arguments.  For example

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd", "/c", command});
```

**Update:** I was wrong, the convenience method [Runtime.exec(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29) already uses a tokenizer to split the command up.  However, this may not be what you want.

Finally, your line

```
while (buffRead.readLine() != null)
```

is incorrect.  This will read a line of input, check it against null and drop it on the floor.  You want something more like

```
String line = null;
while ((line = buffRead.readLine()) != null)
```

What it comes down to is you really should use `ProcessBuilder` to start new processes if you require stream redirection.

Comment: Editing my while loop fixed printing the error and input streams, but it still doesn't split the input and error streams.

Comment: How can you tell?  It looks like `StreamGobbler` is simply reading from a passed in stream and sending it to `System.out`.  Were you trying to do something with the `error` variable?  Maybe something like the following? `System.out.println((error?"[Error] ":"[Out] ")+line.toString());`

Comment: I added a boolean value to the streamgobbler constructor to where it created the errortoken as true and if that boolean was true then I printed the output to the console via System.err.  I feel dumb though because if I just check the waitFor() method to see if it returned a 0 or not would solve my problem.  I do not think I worded my question very well though.  Thank you for helping though.